# Merge two Stack Exchange accounts

Tags: support, merge-accounts, stack-exchange-openid

Yes, I have read the [Stack Overflow help on how to merge accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts), but it does not explain how to merge two Stack Exchange accounts, each being linked with several of the subsites.

I tried:

- to add "merge delete" or "merge keep" to my [Stack Exchange "about me" page](https://stackexchange.com/users/160169/framester), but I did not see how to edit this field.
- to change or add the Stack Exchange OpenID of one of the accounts, to show that both accounts are 'under my control', but the system would not let me.
- to set both accounts to the same email address, but I got following error:

> This email address is already registered. If it belongs to you, log in above or visit our account recovery page to get access to this account.

What should I do?

**[update]**

As explained in the answer I added `merge keep` and `merge delete` to the all the subsite accounts of
https://stackexchange.com/users/58965/derkaiser and
https://stackexchange.com/users/160169/framester.

Could a mod merge these?

**[update2]**

I used the [contact form on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/contact) to ask the two Stack Exchange accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Stack Exchange profile page is not directly editable; it gets copied from one of your site-specific profiles (The oldest by default, IIRC). Just make the edits to your SO profiles. Or any site both accounts exist on, really.

As for merging all the per-site accounts; there's no other way to merge them. Once the merge happens, all the per-site accounts associated with each will be pulled together.

Comment: What does your last para mean ? Will the info/rep/questions/answers of both the accounts be clubbed together or one of them will remain while the other is deleted ?  Sorry for commenting on an old post .