# Merge all accounts of these Stack Exchange-registered users together (not working)

Tags: support, merge-accounts

NOTE: This is not a duplicate because the link this question duplicates does not solve my problem.

OK I've read [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217089/merge-two-stack-exchange-accounts), but I am getting an error when I try to merge the following accounts:

- https://stackexchange.com/users/6423842/jack-maddington
- https://stackexchange.com/users/6005536/jack-maddington
- https://stackexchange.com/users/5961548/john-higginstyne

I want to link all stack exchange accounts (stack overflow, super user, android, english, italian, cooking, software recommendations, home improvement, etc...) so that there will be only one account for all of the Stack Exchange sites where these virtual users have posted. The results should be only one "Jack Maddington" account.

But I am getting an error. Can someone please carry out this operation for me?

Here is a screenshot of the error that I am getting:

[image]

Comment: What's the error?  Did you follow these instructions? http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: I've added a screenshot illustrating the error. Perhaps with this screenshot you can help me. Also, I don't understand why, the user interface shows I'm logged in, but it doesn't show my name and surname in the upper-right hand corner of my Stack Exchange UI.

Comment: Can someone please provide a comment here with some feedback of what I should do before sending me e-mails? Thanks.

Comment: You can't link network profiles. You must put links to your profile **on the same site as the help center**.

Comment: Are you saying that if I have stack overflow, super user, and android enthusiasts, then I must merge them one by one, and confirm each merge separately? Thanks.

Comment: What if one network profile has a diy account, and the other one doesn't have a diy account, how can I merge these. Do I need to create the diy account on the other account first?

Comment: There is something wrong with not being able to link network profiles. These will just linger around forever, purposelessly. At least this is my understanding of it.

Comment: "NOTE: This is not a duplicate because the link this question duplicates does not solve my problem." If you want this question to be reopened, then you should precisely say *why*. Why doesn't it solve your problem?

Comment: You cannot merge accounts using *network profiles*, no. You need to use a *site specific profile* instead. The error message is *entirely correct*. Use links to Stack Overflow accounts instead.

Comment: In other words, you should use https://stackoverflow.com/users/4690814/john-higginstyne and https://stackoverflow.com/users/4979719/jack-maddington. The third network account has no SE accounts associated with it and thus cannot be merged with anything.

Comment: Then delete the account that has no SE accounts associated with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, your second account link has no site linked to it. Which means it is not a valid user and cannot be merged with your other two accounts. And second of all, you need to link two accounts from the same site. Wait. What? FOr example if I attempt to merge your ***network*** profile it won't work, but if I attempt to merge your Italian Language account, it will work.

Doesn't Work:

[image]

Does Work:

[image]

So you should use your two accounts that share the same site. For example:

> https://italian.stackexchange.com/users/1572/jack-maddington

and

> https://italian.stackexchange.com/users/1338/john-higginstyne

Comment: And, to be clear, this will merge the network accounts. There's no need to repeat the process for every shared SE site.

Comment: OK, it was precisely this last comment which made me understand your answer. Perhaps you should include it in the answer proper you gave me.

Comment: Anyways, I would also like to merge the account with no sites. I just would like to get an e-mail confirmation and then log in, post a question, then merge the account. Can you please send me e-mail for this? Thanks. (The reason is that when I search for my own name in the search results I don't want this account every showing up. Thanks.)

Comment: You can't. You have to merge two accounts with sites.